# Keeping div fixed above navbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make `navtop` (dark grey box), currently under the `navbar`, be at the top of the page in that section above the `navbar`, see picture below. I am not great at positioning elements.

[image]
The `navbar` is in a fixed position as well as the div `navtop`.
I am trying to make it so that when you scroll down the page, the main content will go underneath the `navbar` and `navtop`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navtop"></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CrystalDev</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="http://www.crystaldev.net/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products.php">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <?php
            if($_SESSION["active"]==false){
                ?>
                <li class="active"><a href="/signup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="/login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                <?php
            }else{
                switch($_SESSION["rank"]){
                    case 10:
                        ?>
                        <li><a href="/admin.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Admin Panel</a>
                        <?php
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ?>
                        <li><a href="/signout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Sign Out</a>
                        <?php
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navtop {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}

.navbar {
    margin-top: 10%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to remove the `navbar-top-fixed` class from the navbar and add your logic to position both of them at the top (otherwise you will have to have your selector specificity higher than the one used by bootstrap for `navbar-top-fixed` for any changes to get applied.

```css
.navtop {
  height: 8vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 8vh; /*same as the height of navtop*/
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navtop"></div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CrystalDev</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.crystaldev.net/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/products.php">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php
            if($_SESSION["active"]==false){
                ?>
          <li class="active"><a href="/signup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="/login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          <?php
            }else{
                switch($_SESSION["rank"]){
                    case 10:
                        ?>
            <li><a href="/admin.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Admin Panel</a>
              <?php
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ?>
                <li><a href="/signout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Sign Out</a>
                  <?php
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might not be the gray `div` under the navbar. Try increasing the top margin or padding of the content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add **top:0 and position:fixed** ans added some random text to show that position remains fixed of navtop.

```css
.navtop {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    border:2px solid red;
    background-color: tan;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}

.navbar {
    margin-top: 10%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>sda</title>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navtop"></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CrystalDev</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="http://www.crystaldev.net/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/products.php">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <?php
            if($_SESSION["active"]==false){
                ?>
                <li class="active"><a href="/signup.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="/login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                <?php
            }else{
                switch($_SESSION["rank"]){
                    case 10:
                        ?>
                        <li><a href="/admin.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Admin Panel</a>
                        <?php
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        ?>
                        <li><a href="/signout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Sign Out</a>
                        <?php
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<pre>
dsd
sda
sa
dsadsd
sda
d
sdad
dsad
sad
sda
sdsa
sad
sda
sd
sasa
s
sd
s

sdsda
sa
d

</pre>
</body>
</html>
```